# Is this a new type of convex pentagonal tiling?

Tags: tiling

The following pentagon produces a tiling that does not appear to belong to any of the existing 15 categories:

[image]

Here's the tiling:

[image]

Specifically, it is not Type4 or Type6 because those are edge-to-edge tilings while the new tiling is not. Also, in the new tiling's fundamental unit, all the four pentagons meet at vertex 'B' (of my pentagon figure), due to mirroring along X and Y [this doesn't seem to be the case for Type2's pentagons].

Thoughts?

Thanks,

Saty

Comment: I'm not certain about this, but I think one has to distinguish between categories of tilings and categories of tiles. I think there are 15 known categories of tiles. Some of those tiles can give rise to more than one kind of tiling, but that's not what's being counted by the number 15. If I'm right, then the question is whether your *tile* is of a new type. For everyone's convenience, here's a link to a Wikipedia piece on the pentagonal tiling question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling

Comment: In particular, Type 1 is characterized by having two adjacent angles summing to $2\pi$, so your tile fits there.

Comment: Also your whole tiling can be stretched, so only D+E=180° is needed.

Comment: do those really tile? I see some space https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle

Comment: Hi Gerry and Wolfgang and John, thank you for your notes..  John, the polygon does tile - I left a little gap on purpose when I created the figure :)

Comment: In my second comment, where I wrote $2\pi$, what I ought to have written was $\pi$.